# Cannot connect to database with Neo4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

im trying to make a java springboot project using Neo4j in DataBase , when i try to execute and test my Api in postman this error it diplayed to me :

```
Connection to the database terminated. Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0.
```

i had verified what it want for the encryption by adding this line in the **application.properties**:

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:7687
spring.data.neo4j.username=Example1
spring.data.neo4j.password=secret
spring.data.neo4j.database =stud
org.neo4j.driver.config.encrypted=true
```

how can i find a solution for my problem
**Thanks**

Comment: So *have* you ensured that?

Comment: @user207421 yes

Comment: Where is the evidence of that?

Comment: Could you please specify the database and Spring Data Neo4j version, you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and I was solve it by these steps. (There may be another approach as well but this works for me).

1. Created new database(local) in Neo4j
2. Set the password for the database
3. Use the database name in connection, username as "neo4j" and the password which is used to create a project.

After these steps I am able to connect to the Neo4j DB.

Thanks,

Atul